# How do I change a variable in angular 6 using interpolation?

Tags: angular

All I've been trying to do is change 5 to 6 using interpolation, but nothing I'm doing is working :(

[image: dumb variable]

```
component.ts
  x = 5;

  changeX(){
    this.x = this.x + 1;
  }
```

component.html

```
{{x}}

<div>
  wtf{{x.changeX}}
</div>

{{x}}
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what behavior you *want* to see here?  I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works. You'll have to somehow call `changeX`. But you can only do that if there's any DOM event. So I've added `changeX` as a `click` event handler to the `div`. Whenever the `div` is clicked, `x` will increment.

```
{{x}}

<div (click)="changeX()">
  wtf
</div>

{{x}}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d1rrlv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for it.

Comment: I thought that's what {{x.changeX}} does, but it's not working.

Comment: That's not how it works. You'll have to somehow call `changeX`. But you can only do that if there's any DOM event. So I've added changeX as a click event handler to the div. Whenever the div is clicked, `x` will increment.

Comment: Please don't use rude/abusive language here. Consider removing the comment above as it voilates SO's Terms of Use.

Comment: @Siddharth - just curious - what is so rude about his comment? he just shared that its aint working with him?

Comment: it was deleted because I said that I don't like when people just downvote for no real reason. @Deian

Comment: @Brandon - well I hear you but we cannot control what our friends "the trolls" would do  ... got to live with it :)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

in the component:

```
  @Output()
  private x = 5;

  public incX() {
    this.x++;
  }
```

in the template:

```
{{x}}
<div>
  wtf{{incX()}}
</div>
{{x}}
```

Comment: Okay I agree there is something funny with that - seems like NG is calling the template multiple times and my counter is one more than I anticipate but the function call works with the brackets {{incX()}}. Did you try that  - I am interested how it works for you? and what version on NG are you working with?